# Nullablity of DB generated attributes

Tags: orm, null, kotlin, spring-data

I'm working in a Kotlin based project and It force me to deal with any attribute that possibly can hold null. It's nice to find out somewhere nulls are possible while they are not welcome; but I see so much of `?.`s and `.!!`s for attributes that DB generates, e.g. IDs. Maybe I'm abusing that operators?

Is there any convention to mark attribute as not nullable but still have DB generated values here? If I lookup an object It's safe to assume DB generated values are not null anymore. Can VM be made known to this? Maybe by framework or some annotations that language provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id is generated by the database it is nullable since the JVM/compiler/IDE has no way to know if your entity is already persisted or not.

What you could do though is implement additional methods that are guaranteed to return non-null values by throwing an exception otherwise.